# Storing article-length blocks of text and markup in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm implementing a quick and dirty CMS for a content-heavy website and am unsure of how to store the text and markup for "articles," blocks of formatted text that will generally run under 4,000 characters in length, but could theoretically run to 40,000 in unusual circumstance. I have several questions:

1. Is it practical to store text this length in varchar? If not, what should I use?
2. Is there a best practice for storing markup separately from the text it's marking up?
3. Is there a commonly-accepted protocol for storing markup in formats other than HTML? In this case, I want to allow bold, italic, code blocks, and the marking of paragraphs as header, subhead or "byline," which would be handled in a predefined way.
4. Is there a practical way to handle pagination once and store the information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Sure.  Use varchar(MAX) or nvarchar(MAX) for UNICODE.  I believe SQL Server has an 8k page limit, so there may be a performance impact for very large text fields.
2. Why do you want to separate it?  You could just store the HTML.
3. See #2.
4. I think this is impractical since pagination would vary based on how the markup is to be displayed.

Comment: ..and with 2 GB of storage for each entry, that's good enough to store over 250 times the whole contents of *War and Peace* - even in 2-byte-per-character Unicode! :-)

Comment: #3 looks like the OP wants (or has it in mind) to implement some custom markup akin to BBCode or to what is implemented here on SO (asterisks, ticks, 4-space indents...)

Comment: I don't want to store HTML for two reasons: (1) Semantic elements don't always map up to single HTML elements cleanly and may require extra processing. (2) Storing HTML is a bit like storing binary code. It introduces security concerns.